# Android Studio breaking AndroidManifest.xml

Tags: android, android-studio

So it looks like Android Studio is mangling my AndroidManifest file, well at least the one that is in the `../app/build/intermediates/manifests/full/debug` directory.

For example, the following is just one of the corruptions:

```
<application
        android:name="com.myname.myapp.@string/app_name"
```

That makes no sense, right.

It also complains about URI not being registered for the manifest root. Along with `glEsVersion` not being allowed here in "uses feature" tag. "Theme" and "ConfigChanges" are not allowed activity tags..

What is causing this and how do I fix? Thanks.

EDIT:

This is a problem because my app won't compile now.

And please don't close. This IS a relevant question.

Comment: And why does it bother you? Is the app not compiling or..? [Also, do you have such problem with a new, clean project? Have you tried to clean up build folders and re-build everything?]

Comment: Well, it doesn't compile. I can't launch the project. Yes I tried various clean up operations and this is a relatively new project. I just added Google Maps. That is all. Did you vote to close??

Comment: I.e. if you now create new empty project -> add Google maps dependency and Map fragment into layout - it stops compiling?  not me [personally I think that best way to "teach" people - avoid responding poorly designed question :-) ]

Comment: Ok, well I did try that. I did actually also update Android Studio :/

Comment: (if you're using 2.0) Gradle version has also been updated recently. Make sure, your build.gradle file has been correctly updated. for me it's now ` `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-beta2'` and `repositories {
        jcenter()
    }`  . And one more thought: make sure, that you're editing **proper** AndroidManifest file in Android Studio. From time to time, I'm editing `intermediates` version of it and obviously non of my changes being saved. So, just a guess - you real AndroidManifest file might really be corrupted.

Comment: Yea that's all correct .. I'm on 1.5 now.

Comment: Added one more thought into my previous comment. Are you sure, that your AndroidManifest file isn't really corrupted before you are clicking "Run the project"?